# How to pass a file through different components in angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I'm required to handle a photo upload in this I'm survey app building, the problem is, the post request is sent in the next screen.

So I need a way to pass the file through the screens since I can't store it in local storage.

[image: My upload component]

Needs to be passed this next screen ==>

[image: Last screen of the flow]

So when I post the survey, I can store the data in the database and after that, upload the image and relate it to the survey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Here is how you can do it:

1. Create a service that both components would use.
2. Create a property in that service that would store the files.
3. Update that property from the first component with actual files.
4. Fetch the files from the service in second component.

Comment: Thank you so much, I now can access tho the file in the last component. You saved my life.

Answer (score 0):

I did not really understand where you are building the function.
But you can build the function in the service and pass it a parameter
This is how you can call it in any component

Comment: The function is built in `experience.component.ts`, it shows in the `experience.component.html` as you can se in the first image. I need to pass that image to `gender.component.ts` so it can be posted with the rest of the survey

Comment: I do not see the code.
But it sounds like a matter of moving a proop to a son component correctly